# Run stats after creating index on a temporary session based table

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, temporary-objects

Database:- DB2
I have written a procedure which manipulates data to get final output.
Temporary session based tables are used for the same.
Since data volume will be high in those temporary tables, indexes are created.

Can I please get suggestions on if I should **run stats** after index is created??

I read somewhere that run stats is database level and not session level.
What would be the right way to tune huge temporary tables?

Comment: The answer depends on the DB2 version and platform.

Comment: db2 version is 9.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create indexes, one would assume you have conducted performance analysis and determined that those indexes are required. If that is the case, it would be prudent to have current statistics on those indexes, otherwise they may not be as useful.

You can generate index statistics while creating indexes: `CREATE INDEX ... UPDATE STATISTICS`.

You can also rely on automatic RUNSTATS, if it is enabled in your environment, however, given the transient nature of temporary tables, automatic maintenance may not kick in early enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tagged **Oracle** too.

In Oracle, you don't need to **gather statistics** after **creating new index**.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#sthref6626),

> Oracle Database now automatically collects statistics during index
>   creation and rebuild.